# How to get photos from local path and from JSON file with AJAX request . After that append it to html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON file with many pictures in it :
   `[
     {
      "location": "url",
      "title": "title 001",
     }
   ]`

I need to create a Ajax request to that loca json file and display the images as a gallery in the html tag `<img>`

I am not sure once i create the ajax request ,after that in the `takeimages()` what exactly to put as a parameter.

`<div id="pictureGallery"></div>`

`$.ajax({
    url: '..',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cors: true ,
    success: function takeImages()
    { }
});`

`function takeImages(?) {
    ?.forEach(function (item) {`
pictureGallery.append`(``)`
    })
}`

I am a little bit confused because i am new at AJAX requests a all

Comment: `success: function(data)` => data parameter will contain your `json`, at this point you can do something like `data[0].location` or `data[0].title` or pass the data parameter to `renderImages`. So something like this `success: function(data) { renderImages(data); }`

Comment: but in the renderImage() what parameters should i set and after that for the forEach?

Comment: the parameter will be `data` in `renderImages`, you pass the `json` response from `success` to `renderImages(data)` which is an `array`, then you do `data.forEach`

Comment: It worked , thank you so much, but once i make the request in the html the images are not loaded i am just seeing the the code <img src=" ..... " > and not the actual photos. What is wrong with this code
 `imageContainer.append(``<img src=${item.location} id=${item.id}><p>${item.title}</p>`)`  in my function  ?